# How to handle https request if ssl is not installed on server using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-url

I just tried with http ans https to fetch data in the for of json from server, while I try with http its working fine but when I try with https getting error. Is there any way to handle "https" request if server is not cofigured with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

no, there isn't any way if the server isn't configured to user SSL. However if you want TLS encryption you could use a SSH tunnel. If you can't configure your application to use SSL you could configure a http server like Apache or nginx to act as an SSL Proxy.

Comment: is there any way to redirect or replace this https to http, I just tried with htaccess using                                                                                      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L], but its not working.

Comment: puh, I'm sorry I never used codeigniter. Anyway it would be better to configure the server serving the json to use https. You should edit your question and be more explicit about your problem. Add some code examples.

Comment: is there any way to handle these request with .htaccess file,  I just tried many one among them is given here but its not working.                                     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}. here I just tried to rewrite all https to http but its not giving me the exact result.

Comment: no `.htaccess` has nothing to do with SSL/TLS. Maybe you should follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04